Kotlin - Count amount different values from enum property on a list
I have a class called Class that has a property called dayOfWeek. This property is of type DayOfWeek.
I have a list of Class and I want to check how many different days of week appear on this list. So, for example, if I have 8 classes and 3 of them are FRIDAY, 2 are WEDNESDAY and 3 are MONDAY, this method should return 3 (because there are 3 different days of week on this list (MONDAY, WEDNESDAY and FRIDAY)).
Is there a built-in method, or should I create?
If I need to create it, I made this one:
inline fun <T, P> Iterable<T>.countUnique(block: (T) -> P): Int {
    if (this is Collection && isEmpty()) return 0
        var count = 0
        val list: ArrayList<P> = arrayListOf()
        for (element in this) {
            val property = block(element)
            if (list.contains(property).not()) {
                list.add(property)
                count++
            }
        }
        return count
    }
}


A mutable set would be far more efficient than an array list for this, but as the answer shows, there’s already a built-in solution.

You can use this on your list:
distinctBy(Class::dayOfWeek).count()


Thanks! That solved the problem. My question is: How come Class::dayOfWeek is of type (T) -> K, which is what's expected as parameter for the function distinctBy ?

T is the type of the list's elements, K is the type of what should be compared to determine the uniqueness. (T) -> K is therefore a function with a single parameter of your list's type (Class), and the return value is of the type of what you want to be unique, i.e. DayOfWeek. In short, the function should get a DayOfWeek of a Class. That is easy: Each Class instance has a dayOfWeek property of that type. The function body could therfore be as simple as parameter.dayOfWeek...

... Now, a function reference is a static reference to a property of a type. Class::dayOfWeek is such a function reference. It represents a function that returns the dayOfWeek property of a given object of type Class. Function references are just syntax sugar so you don't need to write a lambda expression with parameter names or even an entire function with a function name, just to return a simple property.

I understand how, if I have a function fun dayOfWeek(c: Class): DayOfWeek  { return c.dayOfWeek }, if I call distinctBy(::dayOfWeek), that would work, but I'm unable to see how distinctBy(Class::dayOfWeek) also work when dayOfWeek is a PROPERTY (not function) from Class. I see properties in kotlin similar to Attributes in Java (variable that holds a given type), NOT as functions (such as the parameter (T) -> K). In kotlin I see that if a function requires another function as parameter of type (A) -> B, I can pass A::B where A is a given class and B a property of type B from A. Is that it?

Here is the solution that came up in my mind:
fun countUniqueDays(classes: List<Class>): Int {
    return classes.map { it.dayOfWeek }.distinct().count()
}

This will help you count the unique days in a week for the provided classes!
